# Valid bash won't execute in make

Tags: gnu-make

```
# Makefile

test :
    while true; do
        echo test
    done

test2 :
    while true; do echo test; done
```

`make test` throws the error

```
while true; do
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Makefile:2: test] Error 1
```

whereas `make test2` works just fine. I can not figure out why.

Comment: In make each line of a recipe is a separate standalone shell command. `while true; do` is not a complete shell command.

Comment: @user414777 oh my god I totally forgot >:( thank you!